# Generate custom attributes in check_box_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'd like to generate check box with custom html attributes (to use UJS later). Here is my view code

```
<%= check_box_tag "data-toggle-completed" => "" %>
```

it gives me

```
<input id="__data-toggle-completed______" name="{&quot;data-toggle-completed&quot;=&gt;&quot;&quot;}" type="checkbox" value="1">
```

But I wanted

```
  <input type="checkbox" data-toggle-completed="">
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You must give the custom attributes as fourth arguments, options. The first three arguments are name, value = "1", checked = false. See [check_box_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag).

The code could be like this:

```
<%= check_box_tag :name, 1, false, data: { "toggle-completed" => "" } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using stimulus js so for custom data-action attribute I did the following

```
<%= check_box_tag :select_shipping_address, true , true, data:{action:"change->form#show_form"}%>
```